# SQL SUM between date range in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to `sum` cost based on `ProductId` and `Date`.

My date format is :`YY/MM/DD` and it is `date` The data looks like this:

```
DateFrom     DateTo         Cost     ProductId
07/12/12    | 07/12/31 |    120,5   | 1 
01/12/12    | 11/12/31 |    220 5   | 1 
01/12/12    | 11/12/31 |    120,5   | 1 
08/12/12    | 08/12/31 |    140,5   | 2 
11/12/12    | 11/12/31 |    140,5   | 2 
11/12/12    | 11/12/31 |    140,5   | 2
```

The output i want to get should look like this:

```
FirstDateFrom   LastDateTo   SumOfCostFromSameYear   ProductId
07/12/12       | 07/12/31   |   120,5              | 1  
01/12/12       | 11/12/31   |   341                | 1  
08/12/12       | 08/12/31   |   140,5              | 2  
11/12/12       | 11/12/31   |   281                | 2
```

As you can see, i want to have sum of cots from every `year` in my output.

I started to write some `sql`:

```
SELECT DateFrom, DateTo, ProductId, SUM(cost) FROM CostOfSomething WHERE ...
```

But i dont know how `WHERE` statement should look like for my scenerio

EDIT:
Create script of this table:

```
create table CostOfSomething(
Id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
DateTo DATE,
DateFrom DATE,
Cost NUMBER(6,2),
ProductId NUMBER REFERENCES product(ProductId)
);
```

Comment: Please tag your database ?

Comment: "_My date format is :YYYY/MM/DD._"? `7/12/1` doesn't fit very well.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @VBoka it is oracle database

Comment: Are `dateto` and `datefrom` strings or dates?

Comment: @Mureinik its `date` format

Comment: Please can you wrote full date format for the first row: 7/12/12        | 07/12/31 just so we can understand what is the date format.

Comment: I edited my post, ask if you still dont know something

Comment: Hi @michasaucer, as I have asked, please wrote full date format for the first row: 07/12/12 | 07/12/31. I will give you example: today is 18/03/20 or dd/mm/yy or in full  18/03/2020 or dd/mm/yyyy . Please in this way explain your first row.

Comment: You are right, sorry, it is `YY`

Comment: From the sample data you've given, it looks like you're just looking for a simple `group by`. Is that the case, or is there something more complicated going on that's not shown in the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(DateFrom) "FirstDateFrom"
       , max(DateTo) "LastDateTo"
       , sum(Cost) "SumOfCostFromSameYear"
       , min(ProductId) "ProductId"
from CostOfSomething    
group by to_char(DateFrom, 'yy')
order by to_char(DateFrom, 'yy') -- you do not need to have order by
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15c962cca7d08debad35df6377e271fc)

Comment: Thanks! It works good, but it dont return all `ProductId` by year. In my data set i have 5 rows with `ProductId = 1` but it returns only 3 (all with diffrent years). Why?

Comment: You are welcome :) You asked : "As you can see, i want to have sum of cots from every year in my output." ?

Comment: Add this 2 more rows in your question so I can check what is it that you want, also please edit your expected results. And also please note that you can accept the question but you can also up vote it...

Comment: my bad, it works correctly. Thanks, i upvoted yr answer

Comment: Great! Thanks! Happy to help

Comment: One more question, why you used `min(ProductId)`? What happen there? I dont understand it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209875/discussion-between-vboka-and-michasaucer).